# datetime module not matching int comparison to int

Tags: python

I'm currently making an Alarm Clock as a tool to further learn python3 and I have come across a problem.

```
def clockCheck():
    #get the hour and time from setAlarm
    splitTime = re.compile(r'(\d+?)(:)(\d+)')
    timeRe = splitTime.search(setAlarm())
    alarmHour = timeRe.group(1)
    alarmMinute = timeRe.group(3)

    #get the live time
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    currentHour = now.hour
    currentMinute = now.minute
    currentSecond = now.second

    print(currentHour)
    print(alarmHour)

    while True:
        if currentHour != alarmHour:
            print("check1")
            time.sleep(60-currentSecond) #if this isn't done, the alarm could be off by a couple seconds. Line's up things
            time.sleep((60*60) - (60*currentMinute)) #this sleeps the program until the next hour is hit and reruns a check
        elif currentMinute != alarmMinute:
            print("check2")
            time.sleep(60-currentSecond) #sleep until the next minute and rerun the check

            #play sound
            #break out of program, it's done
```

In this code snippet, when currentHour is compared to alarmHour (the first if statement), even when those two variables are the same, the code executes the if statement in which they do not equal each other.

In other words, if currentHour = 1 and alarmHour = 1,  the code will execute as if currentHour != alarmHour and will run that if statements code. 
Obviously that doesn't make sense and I don't know why that is happening when clearly 1==1. I have posted the full code, feel free to play with it. All these modules are built into python3.6

Here is my full code

```
'''
alarmclock.
ask user for what time to blare off
compare current time to set alarm time
if they do not equal the same then sleep the program for x time and `    rerun the check where it checks if current time is equal alarm time yet. loop until currenttime equals alarm time. then play soun`d

'''
import time
import datetime
import re

def setAlarm():
    print("Hello, what time would you like the alarm to sound? Please input in this format\ne.g. 7:45pm\n")
    time = input("Time: ")

    splitTime = re.compile(r'(\d+?)(:)(\d+?)(pm|am)') #split up time inputted for manipulation
    timeRe = splitTime.search(time)

    hour = int(timeRe.group(1))
    minutes = int(timeRe.group(3))
    dayOfTime = timeRe.group(4).lower() #set pm or am to lowercase for ease

    #errorChecking for proper time format
    if hour > 12 or hour < 1:
        print("Please input your time properly, in 12 hour time")
        setAlarm()

    if minutes > 59 or minutes <  0:
        print("Please input your time properly")
        setAlarm()


    #if time of day is pm, then reassign all values from 1pm - 11:59pm as 13, 14, 15, etc 24 hour bullshit.
    if dayOfTime == "pm" and hour != 12:
        convertedHour = hour + 12

    else:
        convertedHour = hour

    if dayOfTime == "am" and hour == 12:
        convertedHour = 24

    finalTime = str(convertedHour) + ":" + str(minutes)
    print(finalTime)
    return finalTime



def clockCheck():
    #get the hour and time from setAlarm
    splitTime = re.compile(r'(\d+?)(:)(\d+)')
    timeRe = splitTime.search(setAlarm())
    alarmHour = timeRe.group(1)
    alarmMinute = timeRe.group(3)

    #get the live time
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    currentHour = now.hour
    currentMinute = now.minute
    currentSecond = now.second

    print(currentHour)
    print(alarmHour)

    while True:
        if currentHour != alarmHour:
            print("check1")
            time.sleep(60-currentSecond) #if this isn't done, the alarm could be off by a couple seconds. Line's up things
            time.sleep((60*60) - (60*currentMinute)) #this sleeps the program until the next hour is hit and reruns a check
        elif currentMinute != alarmMinute:
            print("check2")
            time.sleep(60-currentSecond) #sleep until the next minute and rerun the check

            #play sound
            #break out of program, it's done


def main():
    clockCheck()

main()
```

Comment: `alarmHour` is not an int.

Comment: I feel dumb for not doing a type check, sorry guys this is only my third week learning python. Please don't shut down my account. Thanks user2357112

Comment: Why is this tagged for both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x... which is it?

Comment: python3, but literally could be translated to python2.7 in seconds if you change input to raw_input. Makes no real big difference. Logic is the same

Comment: Don't tag with a specific Python version *unless your question is specific to that version*. Just use the regular `python` tag otherwise.